# Problem Hosting on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, apache2

I need help

I have a problem with hosting on Ubuntu and Apache2
for months

 I have been trying to host my website on my pc but I have not found any guide, i have removed apache2 and packages and reinstalled but nothing.

 I also thought i needed the Server version of Ubuntu but, if possible, i'd like to work on my main version ... to work on the site and simultaneously keep it online and avoid to switching partitions.

My website is made up of many pages that connect to each other, so i want people to be able to reach the Home page as the first page (of course) and I would also like the site to be reached by other people as well

 I say this because in the first experiments with Apache2 the browser also showed me the index of the working folder, it's a problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `nginx` it is much fast, lightweight and easy.  as mentioned at few places as I read.

open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

after installation of `nginx`. type:

```
service nginx start
```

now open web browser and type localhost if it opens nginx page then your server is running.

To host a website: in terminal type:

```
cd /var/www

/var/www ls
```

here you will find folder html.
here you can copy and paste your website folder. and when you refresh your localhost page on web browser it will open your website.

If in case you want to name your website folder other then html or want to host more then one website. for example your website folder name is "www2". Then in terminal type:

```
cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  /etc/nginx/sites-available/www2
```

in this file you have to change the default path to your website:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/www2
```

in this file you have to make some changes like:

change root /var/www/html; to /var/www/www2
change server_name _; to server_name www2.com;

and save & exit
now to enable your www2 website in terminal type:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

ln -s ../sites-available/www2 www2

cd
```

now to test `nginx` type:

```
nginx -t

service nginx restart
```

To successfully run nginx if you have installed firewall you may need to configure that also.